# solr plain text tokenize

Tags: solr, tokenize

I have a bunch of textfiles with nothing but color-codes. The frequency is the number of times a given color occurs in the file.

000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009 000009
00000b 00000b 00000b 
00000c 00000c 00000c 00000c
00000e 00000e

I have seen this http://www.slideshare.net/clbecker/lucene-revnov2014 and I'm trying to get the solr-part right. I have defined a filetype with the white-space-tokenizer and added a field of that type. Problem is I don't know how to import the file as it is. How do I tell solr (solr 5) to extract the content using that tokenizer? I guess I could make it a structured file (csv) and then do it the standard way - like solr/update --data @csv-file. But it seems overkill for such a simple file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update request to do it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers

Comment: But isn't this is for either tika-based updates or standard types - csv, json? This is more simple - all content is just one field-type.

Comment: So, you just have a CSV with one field. And your document represents one image. You may want to think what you want to do for IDs though. Auto-generate them with UpdateRequestProcessor chain or adjust schema to not have them. Better, of course, to have them.

Comment: I was expecting too much or did not understand solr well enough. I did indeed have to turn my data into something structured. And that was actually very little work - ended up with json and two fields. Thanx